# Remove item if checkbox is checked to-do list

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm building my own to-do list web application. I've setted up everything but there is one thing left. I want if one checkbox is checked, remove it from the array. How can I do this using DOM or anything? I've found some solutions on stackoverflow but couldn't realised how to use it with my own code. Please help me :)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7xFN.jpg)
html:

```
<%- include("header") -%>

  <div class="box hidden" id="heading">
    <h1> <%= listTitle %> </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box hidden" id="todo">
    <% for (i = 0; i < newListItem.length; i++) { %>
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="remove">
      <p> <%= newListItem[i] %> </p>
    </div>
    <% }; %>
    <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
      <button type="submit" name="list" value=<%= listTitle %>>+</button>
    </form>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//animation
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#heading').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('hidden');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#todo').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('hidden');
});

</script>

<%- include("footer") -%>
```

app.js:

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const date = require(__dirname + '/date.js')

const app = express();
let items = ["Buy Chocolate" , "Heat Chocolate" , "Eat Chocolate"];
let schoolItems = [];


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {

  let day = date.getDate();
  res.render("todolist", {
    listTitle: day,
    newListItem: items
  });
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  let item = req.body.newItem;
  if (req.body.list === "School") {
    schoolItems.push(item);
    res.redirect("/school");
  } else {
    items.push(item);
    res.redirect("/");
  }

})

app.get("/school", function (req, res) {
  res.render("todolist", {
    listTitle: "School List",
    newListItem: schoolItems
  });
});

app.get("/about", function (req, res) {
  res.render("about");
})


app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
})
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do, if it's only UI specific then post your UI code only, if it's backend/nodejs related put nodejs code only. It will be much easier if scope  the problem.

Comment: I want if the checkbox checked with related item, remove it from `items` array and remove it from the user interface also.

Comment: In that case, you will have to write a new route in your server-side express code and you would also need to change how you are storing `items`, for instance, you need to have an `id` for each item in your list.

Comment: This is a very broad scope, break the problem into sub problems, how to do that action in UI, then how to send the response to backend to sync this is backend data model.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in my todo list using express and ejs

Body of ejs file

```
<body>
    <form id = "new-item-form" action = "/create-item" method = "POST">
        <input type = "text" name = "description" placeholder = "task">
        
        <button type = "submit">ADD TASK</button>
        <button formaction="/remove-item" type="submit"> DELETE TASKS </button>

        <ul>
            <% for( var i = 0; i < item_list.length; i++) { %>
            <li class = "item">
                <input type = "checkbox" name = "check" value = "<%= item_list[i]._id %>"/>
                <div class = "details">
                    <p><%= item_list[i].description %></p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <% } %>
        </ul>
    </form>
</body>
```

Controller to remove items:-

```
const Item = require('../models/todo');
module.exports.remove = function(req, res){  
var removeList = req.body.check;

if(typeof removeList === "string"){
    Item.findByIdAndDelete(removeList, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log('error');
            return;
        }
    });
}
else if(typeof removeList === "object"){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < removeList.length ; i++){
        Item.findByIdAndDelete(removeList[i], function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log('error');
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}
return res.redirect('back');}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done like this you can refer it.

```
    <%- include("header") -%>

  <div class="box" id="heading">
    <h1> <%= listTitle %> </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box">

  <%  newListItems.forEach(function(item) { %>
      <form class="" action="/delete" method="post">
        <div class="item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%=item._id%>" onChange="this.form.submit()">
          <p><%=  item.name  %></p>
        </div>
      </form>
  <%  }); %>


      <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
        <button type="submit" name="list">+</button>
      </form>
  </div>

<%- include("footer") -%>
```

App.js code

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB",  {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true
 });

 const itemsSchema = {
   name: String
 };

 const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);

 const item1 = new Item ({
   name: "Welcome to your TodoList!"
 });

 const item2 = new Item ({
   name: "Hit the + button to add a new item."
 });

 const item3 = new Item ({
   name: "<-- Hit this to delete an item."
 });

const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];


const today = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: '2-digit'}).format(new Date());


app.get("/", function(req, res) {

  Item.find( {}, function(err, foundItems) {

    if(foundItems.length === 0) {
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Successfully added all the documents");
        }
      });
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      res.render("list", {listTitle: today , newListItems: foundItems});
    }

  });



});

app.post("/", function(req, res){

  const itemName = req.body.newItem;

  const item = new Item({
    name: itemName
  });

  item.save();
  res.redirect("/");

});

app.post("/delete", function(req, res) {
  const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
  Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId , function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("Successfully deletd the Id");
    }
    res.redirect("/");
  });
});



app.get("/work", function(req,res){
  res.render("list", {listTitle: "Work List", newListItems: workItems});
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
  res.render("about");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one: Mongoose data deletion from checkbox using express js

```
app.post("/delete", function (req, res) {
      const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox
      noteModel.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId , function (err) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log("succefully deleted")
          res.redirect("/")
        }
      })
})
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.